# Using Font Awesome in MVC5 Html grid column

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, grid, font-awesome

I am attempting to use Font Awesome in my MVC5 Html grid, as shown in my code segment below. On executing the code below, the grid renders correctly but the text within the @Html.Raw() declaration is displayed in the cell on the grid, as opposed to the Font Awesome icon. I am using Font Awesome elsewhere on the view, outside of the grid and the icons render correctly, so I'm confident that Font Awesome is installed and configured correctly.

```
@helper CustomRendering(Customer customer)
{
   if (customer.RequiresAssistance)
   {
       @Html.Raw("<i class=\"fab fa-accessible-icon\"></i>");
   }
}

@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
{
   columns.Add().RenderValueAs(o => CustomRendering(o));
})
```

Answer (score -1):

@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
{
   columns.Add().Sanitized(false).Encoded(false).SetWidth(15).RenderValueAs(o => CustomRendering(o));
})